# Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

Tags: ropsten, web3.py, infura, web3-providers, exceptions

i got ***"web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?
"*** error when try to run this code:

```
from web3.auto.infura import w3
import json
from eth_account import Account


account=Account()

contract_address=w3.toChecksumAddress("0xd2980a7c0c97b47cf1dd22ececc4071fcfc0ef86")
bytecode="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"
abi=json.loads('[{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"_candidateId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"votedEvent","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"candidates","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"id","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"voteCount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"candidatesCount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_candidateId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"voters","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]')

contract=w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address,abi=abi)

vote_count=contract.functions.candidatesCount().call()
candidates=[]
choices=[]
for i in range(vote_count):
        d=contract.functions.candidates(i+1).call()
        candidates.append(d)
        choices.append((d[0],d[1]))     


class Canlist(forms.Form):
    cfiels=forms.ChoiceField(required=True,choices=choices)
def vote(i):
    #a=contract.functions.vote(i).transact()
    construct_txn = contract.functions.vote(i).buildTransaction({
    'from': acct.address,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address),
    'gas': 1728712,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('30', 'gwei')})

    signed = acct.signTransaction(construct_txn)
    b=w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    tx_receipt=w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(b)
    return tx_receipt


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        n=request.POST.get('cfiels')
        aa=vote(int(n))
        if aa:
            context={
            'candidates':candidates,
            }
            return render(request,'voting/result.html',context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('failed')






    form=Canlist()

    context={
        #'candidates':candidate,
        'form':form
        }

    return render(request,'voting/home.html',context)
```

my contract is:https://ropsten.etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xd2980a7c0c97b47cf1dd22ececc4071fcfc0ef86

Any ideas??please leave your thoughts as possible?

Comment: As the address is correct and the contract is deployed - is your chain synchronized with the Ropsten network?

Comment: how to check my ropsten chain is synchronized?

Comment: if you use Infura it should be synchronized. if you use a local node you have to check its status

Comment: Yes,i am using infura.But i can't understand problem.Checked my contract address all are correct,any suggestions?